# Overlapping error messages

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, design, documentation-editor

This's a minor design problem -- the error messages break through the editor view:

[image: Image 1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with the next build, we'll combine multiple errors on the same item:

> [image]