# Error message box overlapping the title bar

Tags: discussion, bug, asking-questions, user-interface, error-message

Recently I noticed that while asking question on Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow, the error message box is overlapping in the title bar.

Please check the below screenshots:

#### Screenshots while asking a question on Stack Overflow

[image]

#### Screenshots while asking a question on Meta Stack Overflow

[image]

I have done some research related to this and I found some posts like this:

1. *[Overlapping error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336611/overlapping-error-messages)*
2. *[Error & warning message box overlapping in question's title](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360488/error-warning-message-box-overlapping-in-questions-title)*

But the post is not related with the overlapping title bar.

**Is that a bug?**